# Wrong formatting while using Tabular Inlines in Django admin

Tags: django, admin

I use Django 1.5.1 out of the box in a virtual environment in my Mac.
I just created an app with two models, so the one can be used as inline in the form of the other.
While reducing the width of my browser I notice that the table inside the inline, does not keep the same width with the other elements in the page. See pictures.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuncH.png "problem"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyMYg.png "detail"

I have used a brand new installation with only the necessary to make admin run.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: i have never seen this issue. It could be some formatting issue in 1.5 .

Comment: It's quite normal for the inlines to bleed beyond the page, but I've never seen the header a different width than the table.